# Agile Toolkit : Redirect on another page with arguments

Tags: php, atk4, agiletoolkit

I just started learning ATK.

In my project, I have a grid of a Model 'A'.
There are many rows for Model 'A'.

I have a separate page for that Model that shows its details.

Now, I want, my grid rows clickable and it should redirect to that page
with 'ID' as argument. So, I can get it and load it again. To show
its details on that page.

How to achieve this?

Comment: This is doable what you're asking for, but why not simply using CRUD already fully implemented in ATK4?

Comment: But, I want its UI completely customized. CRUD/Grid may have button, but that's not much user friendly. If anyone want to see detail of that row, he will usually click on row, not a button on that row.

Comment: Then you have to add small JavaScript onClick method on grid table row. Something like $grid->js(true)->univ()->find('tr')->click(function(){doSomething();});

Answer (score 0):

It should be easily possible with ->on handler.

```
$page=$this->api->url('./subpage');

if($crud->grid) {
    $crud->grid->on('click','tr')->univ()->location(
        array($page, 'id'=>$this->js()->_selectorThis()->data('id'))
    );
}
```

if `->on()` is not working in your version of toolkit, you can also use `->js('click')->_selector('#'.$crud->grid->getJSID().' tr')->univ()->location......;`

Some documentation here:

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/4.3/lib/AbstractView.php#L546